# Can AFNetworking return data synchronously (inside a block)?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, synchronous, afnetworking

I have a function using AFJSONRequestOperation, and I wish to return the result only after success. Could you point me in the right direction? I'm still a bit clueless with blocks and AFNetworking specifically.

```
-(id)someFunction{
    __block id data;

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json){
            data = json;
            return data; // won't work
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

        }];



    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation: operation];

    return data; // will return nil since the block doesn't "lock" the app.
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To block the execution of the main thread until the operation completes, you could do `[operation waitUntilFinished]` after it's added to the operation queue. In this case, you wouldn't need the `return` in the block; setting the `__block` variable would be enough.

That said, I'd strongly discourage forcing asynchronous operations to synchronous methods. It's tricky to get your head around sometimes, but if there's any way you could structure this to be asynchronous, that would almost certainly be the way to go.

Comment: Hey matt , thanks for the reply. Usually i do use my data asynchronously , but specifically for this i have to return some data from an API , so i don't really see another way, unless you can recommend some way of action? :)

Comment: You could always add a block parameter to the method, like `-someFunctionWithBlock:^(NSData *data) {...}`.

Comment: As i said i'm quite of a newbie with blocks, how will this help? (and more importantly , what does it mean to have a block parameter in the method?)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense ! thanks for the lesson, i truly appreciate it :) I'll try writing one method this way and if it works for my needs i will definitely make it a habit :P

Comment: Just wanted to say a big thank you, i just did what you said and i can't see how i managed without it! so simple and powerful!:)

Comment: I cannot figure out how to set a timeout. What if I do a POST request? Do I have to wait more then two minutes? This keeps me from switching to AFNetworking. For the timeout issue see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8714479/601466

Comment: Unfortunately waitUntilFinished trick doesn't work for me. I've got a couple of business methods that are synchronous by nature. It's a shame that AFNetworking completely ignores such use case.

Comment: I suspect the `waitUntilFinished` trick isn't working for some because the success and failure blocks are (by default) executed using `dispatch_async` on the main queue after the operation is completed.  If you aren't executing inside a runloop, e.g a unit test, then the program may exit early without giving GCD a chance to run the callbacks.

Comment: I think ideally any networking SDK should allow the user to choose if they want asynchronous operations or not; it should not force a particular model, though it may suggest one.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using semaphores to solve this issue. This code is implemented in my own class inherited from `AFHTTPClient`.

```
__block id result = nil;
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
NSURLRequest *req = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                       path:@"someURL"
                                 parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *reqOp = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:req
                                                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                  result = responseObject;                                                                          
                                                                  dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                                                              }
                                                              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                  dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                                                              }];
reqOp.failureCallbackQueue = queue;
reqOp.successCallbackQueue = queue;
[self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:reqOp];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
return result;
```

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest that you don't make a synchronous method with AFNetworking (or blocks in general). A good approach is that you make another method and use the json data from the success block as an argument.

```
- (void)methodUsingJsonFromSuccessBlock:(id)json {
    // use the json
    NSLog(@"json from the block : %@", json); 
}

- (void)someFunction {
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json){
            // use the json not as return data, but pass it along to another method as an argument
            [self methodUsingJsonFromSuccessBlock:json];
        }
        failure:nil];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation: operation];
}
```

Comment: Does `json` need to be retained somewhere so the instance isn't deallocated? I'm assuming the AFNetworking code is autoreleasing it.

Comment: Under ARC, while the block is executing, it would be retained by the block.

Comment: or a more modern way, use `NSNotification`.

Comment: Useless! Do you know that if your app send requests in a concrete order then in most cases it doesn't mean that app will process the responses in the same order? The only ways I found out are synchronous requests and promisekit (and similar libraries

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that some features of AFNetworking's AFClient can still be used in a synchronous manner, meaning that you can still use niceties such as Authorisation headers and multipart uploads.

For example:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self.client requestWithMethod: @"GET"
                                                  path: @"endpoint"
                                            parameters: @{}];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                             returningResponse: &response
                                                         error: &error];
```

Remember to check `response.statusCode` in this case, as this method doesn't consider HTTP failure codes as errors.

Comment: With self.client representing an instance of AFHTTPClient

Comment: This was perfect for my needs, thank you. I wanted a method I could call from the debugger running on our client that would provide "curl" like queries against our REST backend, without needing to reimplement the  OAUTH yack shaving that the client already manages. It's probably also suitable for tests and other non interactive tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Add this below the code you normally work with:

```
[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];
// do what you want
// return what you want
```

Example:

```
+ (NSString*) runGetRequest:(NSString*)frontPath andMethod:(NSString*)method andKeys:(NSArray*)keys andValues:(NSArray*)values
{
    NSString * pathway = [frontPath stringByAppendingString:method];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathway]];
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:pathway
                                                      parameters:params];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
{
            // Success happened here so do what ever you need in a async manner
} 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
{
            //error occurred here in a async manner
}];
        [operation start];
        [operation waitUntilFinished];

         // put synchronous code here

        return [operation responseString];
}
```

Comment: `[operation waitUntilFinished];` has no effect on blocks.

Answer (score 1):

To expand/update @Kasik's answer. You can create a category on AFNetworking like so using semaphores:

```
@implementation AFHTTPSessionManager (AFNetworking)

- (id)sendSynchronousRequestWithBaseURLAsString:(NSString * _Nonnull)baseURL pathToData:(NSString * _Nonnull)path parameters:(NSDictionary * _Nullable)params {
    __block id result = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
    [session GET:path parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        result = responseObject;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return result;
 }

@end
```

If you are calling the sync block inside a completion block of another AFNetwork request, make sure you change the `completionQueue` property. If you don't change it, the synchronous block will call the main queue upon completion while already on the main queue and will crash your application.

```
+ (void)someRequest:(void (^)(id response))completion {
    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] sessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("name", 0);
    session.completionQueue = queue;
    [session GET:@"path/to/resource" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
     NSDictionary *data = [session sendSynchronousRequestWithBaseURLAsString:@"" pathToData:@"" parameters:nil ];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          completion (myDict);
      });
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion (error);
    });
}];
```