# AFNetworking HTTPRequestOperation need to set array from completion block but this isn't working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking with AFHTTPRequestOperation to pull XML data from a webservice. This is working fine and im getting the data I need but I need to split this data into objects and initialize a NSMutableArray with this data. This is working in the completion block, but just before I return the array in my method the data is gone? How do I do this?

Here is some of my code:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString* response = [operation responseString];
    NSData* xmlData = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *xmlError;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&xmlError];
    NSArray *allElements = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"Misc"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *current in allElements)
    {
        NSString *titel;
        NSString *tekst;

        NSArray *titels = [current elementsForName:@"Titel"];
        if(titels.count > 0)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *firstTitel = (GDataXMLElement *) [titels objectAtIndex:0];
            titel = firstTitel.stringValue;
        } else continue;

        NSArray *teksts = [current elementsForName:@"Tekst"];
        if(teksts.count > 0)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *firstTekst = (GDataXMLElement *) [teksts objectAtIndex:0];
            tekst = firstTekst.stringValue;
        } else continue;

        HVMGUniversalItem *item = [[HVMGUniversalItem alloc] initWithTitel:titel AndTekst:tekst];
        [result addObject:item];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i", result.count);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [operation error]);
}];

[operation start];
NSLog(@"%i", result.count);
return result;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the data present in the array when returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't the data present in the array when returning?

Because **AFNetworking** use an async pattern. So the return code will be performed before the operation will be completed.

You need to use a different approach or follow [Can AFNetworking return data synchronously (inside a block)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969865/can-afnetworking-return-data-synchronously-inside-a-block/7970037#7970037). The latter is discouraged.

A solution could be to:

-> Create a `NSOperationQueue` within your class that will include your operation. Create it as a property for your class like.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSOperationQueue* downloadQueue;

- (NSOperationQueue*)downloadQueue
{
    if(downloadQueue) return downloadQueue;

    downloadQueue = // alloc init here
}
```

-> Create a property for your array (synthesize also it)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* result;
```

-> Wrap your code within a specific method like `doOperation`.

```
self.result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

__weak YourClass* selfBlock = self; 

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString* response = [operation responseString];
    NSData* xmlData = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *xmlError;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&xmlError];
    NSArray *allElements = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"Misc"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *current in allElements)
    {
        NSString *titel;
        NSString *tekst;

        NSArray *titels = [current elementsForName:@"Titel"];
        if(titels.count > 0)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *firstTitel = (GDataXMLElement *) [titels objectAtIndex:0];
            titel = firstTitel.stringValue;
        } else continue;

        NSArray *teksts = [current elementsForName:@"Tekst"];
        if(teksts.count > 0)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *firstTekst = (GDataXMLElement *) [teksts objectAtIndex:0];
            tekst = firstTekst.stringValue;
        } else continue;

        HVMGUniversalItem *item = [[HVMGUniversalItem alloc] initWithTitel:titel AndTekst:tekst];
        [selfBlock.result addObject:item];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i", result.count);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [operation error]);
}];

[downloadQueue addOperation:operation];
```

-> if you need to notify that `result` has object send a notification, use the delegate pattern, etc...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for this explanation. I should do more to flesh out asynchronous networking as a concept in the documentation.

Comment: @mattt Thank you! Maybe I'm wrong but are you an author of AFNetworking? Cheers.