# AFNetworking are not writing a response in variable

Tags: cocoa, asynchronous, afnetworking

I have a problem code with using AFNetworking:

```
#import "SyncProfile.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@implementation SyncProfile: NSObject 
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;


- (BOOL)syncProfile {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *token =[userDefaults objectForKey:@"token"];
    int user_id = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"];
    if([token length]) {

        self.profileData = [[self sendRequest:@"method.get" token:token withUser:user_id andParameters:@"param1,param2"] valueForKeyPath:@"response"];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.profileData);

        return YES;
     } else
         return NO;

}

-(id)sendRequest:(NSString *)apiMethod token:(NSString *)token withUser:(int)user_id andParameters:(NSString *)param {

NSMutableString *apiLink = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"https://domain.com/method/%@?uid=%@&fields=%@&access_token=%@", apiMethod, user_id, param, token];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:apiLink];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
        self.req = JSON;
        [self myMethod:JSON];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];
    [operation start];
    return self.req;
}

- (id)myMethod:(id)data {
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
    return 0;
}

@end
```

I need to return a variable with the result AFNetworking back method. But the result is given much later than the method returns. When I use a different method to handle the result, it does not. Tried to use the `[operation waitUntilFinished]` but nothing has changed.

Result in Xcode Output:

```
//Return variable from "sync" method
2013-02-26 23:57:29.793 walkwithme[13815:11303] (null)
//Return from AFN response
2013-02-26 23:57:31.063 walkwithme[13815:11303] {response = ({someJSON})}
//Return from MyMethod
2013-02-26 23:57:31.063 walkwithme[13815:11303] {response = ({someJSON})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use any `wait` methods. What you need to do is have a call back in your success and failure blocks. You can do this the way I showed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040463/how-to-return-a-response-object-using-afjsonrequestoperation/15042250#15042250) you could also do something else like message passing. The key thing to realize is you won't be using the typical method return pattern. Reason being with asynchronous methods like this you have no idea when it will finish which is why it uses the block call backs. Like I said you definitely don't want to `wait` because that could entirely block your application.

EDIT:

I use this code in one of my projects:

Declare method

```
- (void)postText:(NSString *)text
     forUserName:(NSString *)username
   ADNDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
       withBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error))block;
```

Then inside this method I pass those parameters to the network request.

Return values in the block with:

```
if (block) {
    block(responseObject, someError);
}
```

Then I call it with this:

```
[[KSADNAPIClient sharedAPI] postText:postText
                             forUserName:username
                           ADNDictionary:parameters
                               withBlock:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
               // Deal with error
        } else {
               // Probably success!
        }
    }
```

This way the called method returns it's values to the caller method inside the block. I think about it that it defers the block to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, for answer! I'll try to do this, but if I look at to pass variables and run the required method for processing? It will be a valid?