# Wait for block to complete before returning object

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(NSNumber *)method:{

   NSString *url = urlToPost;
   NSNumber *success = [[NSNumber alloc]init];

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerObject POST:url parameters:@{} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        success = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        success = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

   }]; 

   return success;

}
```

Everytime this method is called success is returned as `null`. I have tried dispatching the block on the main queue as other similar StackOverflow answers suggest but the same problem persists.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969865/can-afnetworking-return-data-synchronously-inside-a-block?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

success is null because it is returned before getting assigned inside the block. 
**An asynchronous method runs the code in a background thread and calls the block at a later time.** 
The rest of the function is executed  without wait after the function`AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerObject POST:url parameters:@{} success:^` is called.
Thus the execution of the `return success` may take place before the completion block is called in the asynchronous function.

Comment: i've tried dispatching the block on the mainthread but the same problem persists. is there anyway to make it wait for the block before returning?

Comment: No, the function will complete asynchronously because the network activity will take some time - Event driven programming is an important concept in modern app development so you should learn how to work with it.  In this case you need to invoke a method to process the success/fail from the block rather than relying on the return of the method.